# Why does setjmp(3) not save all registers on AMD64?

Tags: x86-64, setjmp

I was browsing through the source of various `setjmp` and `longjmp` implementations and noticed that not all of the CPU registers are saved in the `jmp_buf` structure. After reviewing the AMD64 ABI, I noticed that only the callee-saved registers are saved.

I do not understand how the function state can be fully resumed when only some of the registers have been saved. Surely the unsaved registers must have been clobbered many times over and over until I call `longjmp` later on?

Everything works perfectly however, so there's definitely something that I don't understand. I was hoping someone could shed some light on this.

Thanks!

Comment: There are implementations of setjmp that do only save the instruction pointer/frame pointer (see `libunwind`). Those have very fast setjmp but relatively slow longjmp times and are based on frame tables that describe how to recover the other registers from caller-saved locations and such.

Comment: Where could I find the source you were looking at?

Comment: @AljoshaBre These are the most readable I've found so far: [setjmp](http://git.etalabs.net/cgi-bin/gitweb.cgi?p=musl;a=blob;f=src/setjmp/x86_64/setjmp.s;h=98f58b8d6551e391f426fc53c81678a03ac89074;hb=HEAD) and [longjmp](http://git.etalabs.net/cgi-bin/gitweb.cgi?p=musl;a=blob;f=src/setjmp/x86_64/longjmp.s;h=e175a4b9606bba41eccc8972c22244e533718f0a;hb=HEAD).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `setjmp` function is a function like any other, and can therefore be assumed to clobber any caller-saved registers. As such, there's no need for it to save/restore those registers.

Comment: Isn't the compiler free to use any of the available registers as it pleases inside my function, i. e. even the registers that are not saved by `setjmp`?

Comment: Not entirely -- it can't use caller-saved registers across a function call, because they can/will be changed. For instance, consider `eax` (on x86): the callee will write a return value into that register, so the caller can't store anything important there across a function call.

Comment: @haste i've falled for this too. to describe it in a little more detail: since they are caller-saved, and setjmp is regarded as a normal function, the caller of setjmp already saves those registers if needed, so when setjmp returns to the caller the second time (by longjmp), the caller will have stored the respective caller-saved registers before and will be able to restore them.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb Ah, that makes so much more sense now. Thanks a lot for the clarification.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb but if it's like a normal function, after the first time setjmp returns, the caller doesn't need to have the caller saved registers saved anymore. Or does it? The stackframe of setjmp call should've been destroyed after it's execution.